# Sharing Config settings between Web App and Console App

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'd like to share my VS2010 3.5 Web Apps settings with my Console App's (2 projects in the same solution).

eg connection string, smtp, log4net settings

This looked close:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/15/how-to-share-configuration-files-between-projects.aspx

Comment: The format of the files is slightly different which would probably make it really difficult to share settings across each project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big difference is step 1 (save  your special settings in external .config files)

1. Put your shared .config into external files (attribute on element: configSource="mySpecialConfig.config")
2. Add the files in a common folder in your solution
3. Add the files as linked items to each project

Comment: Many thanks.. I'm using the new web.debug.config etc.. transformations in VS2010, which are really quite good.  Think I'll just go manual with the console app.config for now :-)