# ASP.NET MVC WebConfig with linked config file causes exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a large ASP.NET MVC project with a data access layer that uses Entity Framework. As well, I have a Windows service project (in a different solution) that makes use of the same DAL project. I have my Web.config/App.config setup so that the connection strings are loaded from a separate `connection.config` file that is in a shared location. The connection configuration is linked (`Add Existing Item > Add As Link`)  in both projects with `Build Action = Content` and the `Copy To Output Directory = Copy if newer`.

The Windows service project runs with no issues, I can see the service connecting to my database correctly. However the ASP.NET MVC project throws an excpetion saying `Unable to open configSource file 'connection.config'. (C:\Path\To\My\web.config line 9)`.

I checked that the `connection.config` file is copied to output directory. I also tried making a copy of the `connection.config` file in the ASP.NET project (instead of linking it) and this runs just fine. Why does linking the file suddenly cause an exception?

My files below for reference

**App.config (Windows service)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connection.config" />
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  [...]
  <connectionStrings configSource="connection.config" />
  [...]
</configuration>
```

**connection.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=./localhost;Initial Catalog=MyBatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Edit**

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437340/appsettings-in-app-or-web-config-using-a-linked-file) answer that works, however I'm concerned how this would affect the application in release mode or when it's deployed. As well I still don't understand why having the file linked has a different behavior than when it's copied in.

Comment: What's the full error? Is your _connection.config_ copied to the same directory as _web.config_?

Comment: That is the full error text of the inner exception, the wrapping exception message simply says `The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception`. The `web.config` isn't copied to the output at all.

Comment: _web.config_ doesn't get copied to the bin folder; it is published to the application web root. When you Copy to Output Directory, the file is copied to the bin folder. Your web app is trying to locate the _connections.config_ in the same folder as your _web.config_ but it can't find it. For the Windows service, it locates the config file in bin which is why it works there.

Comment: A possible solution is to use a post-build step to copy _connection.config_ next to the _web.config_.