# Read config properties from another project in the same solution C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config

I have a solution named **WebServiceProject**.

Inside this solution I have three projects:

- **Common** *(Class Library)*
- **UserInterface** *(WinForms Project)*
- **WebService** *(WCF Service Project)*

In the **WebService** project I have an `app.config` file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b72a5b561321d079">
      <section name="WebService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b72a5b561321d079" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="mydatabase@localhost"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings/>
    <client/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In the **WebService** project I execute some scheduled routine calling the **Common** project classes reading the `ConnectionString` from `app.config` file:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
{
    // I do something
}
```

If I start the **WebService** alone everything works fine.

Inside the *WinForms* project **UserInterface**, I have a button that start the routine inside the **Common** project as the **WebService** does.

But if I "*Set as StartUp project*" the **UserInterface** project the previous piece of code `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]` throw an error, because I didn't specified the `ConnectionString` in the `app.config` in **UserInterface** project.

So, my question is: how can I read the `ConnectionString` property from the **WebService** project event if I "*Set as StartUp project*" the **UserInterface** project? More in general, how can I read an `app.config` property from another project different from the executed one?

Comment: You can have the AppSettings in a own file and link the same file info multiple config-files. as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437340/appsettings-in-app-or-web-config-using-a-linked-file

Comment: @DanielStackenland thank you, this resource is very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link very useful:

[AppSettings in App or Web Config Using a Linked File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437340/appsettings-in-app-or-web-config-using-a-linked-file)

Thanks to @*Daniel Stackendland*

Answer (score 1):

Simply read the file and parse it as an `XML`. Then retrieve your `value` reading the interested `key`.

Comment: I'm trying to use the `System.Configuration` assembly. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get that property from the other project `app.config`.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your application settings from your webservice project into the app.config of your UI-project.

Comment: In production I'll run both projects. So, I would like to have a single `app.config` file where configuration settings are defined.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what you do. Yout put the lines with the values from the webservice-project into yout config of your UI-project

Comment: But I don't want to duplicate the configuration. I would like to have a single file where `config` is available. And this file should be placed in the `WebService` project.